# Setting up drop down selection in Active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have setup Active_admin, where I have one field Is_test(boolean) but I want when it start it only show false records of is_test. Following is code in my active_admin table file which is working fine, but when I click on pagination it gives me error.

```
controller do
      before_action is_test: :index do
        if params[:format] != 'csv'
          params[:q] = {is_test_eq: false} if params[:commit].blank?
        end
      end
end
```

If I remove `is_test:` from above code it works, but than true is selected. I just want to sure that it should select false is_test drop down.

I have added following to show it as drop down in filter section

```
 filter :is_test, label: "Test orders"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with many different solutions and tutorials, I found out there was no straight way but I used url and played with Parameters to get result.

Following is code which allow me to show appropriate results.

```
        if params[:order].blank?
          params[:q] = {is_test_eq: false} if params[:commit].blank?
        end
```

First I check if page number is empty `params[:page]` but it give me incorrect result when I pressed `<<First` button, then I have finally select this where `params[:order].blank?`, and I also used commit so no filter is applied. This gave me pass from QA. All done.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but I would do something like this:

- do not amend your controller
- and add a default scope like this:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register YourResource do
  scope("Non-test") { |scope| scope.where(is_test: false) }, default: true # assuming there is no scope in model class
  scope :all # In case you want to see all cases
end
```

This solution would not give you a dropdown menu but a clickable button where you can filter out tests from non-tests.... this is for your index page by the way.